# Custom Module Grid/Collection class not found

Tags: module, magento-2.2.5

In my custom created module I'm trying to get the grid page in admin working.

I have everything routed, and I'm able to get to the correct page (so i see all of the magento elements, but my grid has an error). When the page is loaded I get the error:

```
Class Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Grid\Collection does not exist
```

My collection code is as followed:

```
namespace Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection as StoreCollection;

use \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * Collection for displaying grid of sales documents
 */
class Collection extends StoreCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
/**
 * @var AggregationInterface
 */
protected $aggregations;

/**
 * @param EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
 * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param MetadataPool $metadataPool
 * @param mixed|null $mainTable
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix
 * @param mixed $eventObject
 * @param mixed $resourceModel
 * @param string $model
 * @param null $connection
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
    $mainTable,
    $eventPrefix,
    $eventObject,
    $resourceModel,
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
    $connection = null,
    AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $storeManager,
        $metadataPool,
        $connection,
        $resource
    );
    $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
    $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
    $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
    $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
}

/**
 * @return AggregationInterface
 */
public function getAggregations()
{
    return $this->aggregations;
}

/**
 * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
 * @return $this
 */
public function setAggregations($aggregations)
{
    $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
}

/**
 * Get search criteria.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
 */
public function getSearchCriteria()
{
    return null;
}

/**
 * Set search criteria.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get total count.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTotalCount()
{
    return $this->getSize();
}

/**
 * Set total count.
 *
 * @param int $totalCount
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set items list.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setItems(array $items = null)
{
    return $this;


  }
}
```

My di.xml is as followed:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="store_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">wavelabs_storelocator_stores</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">store_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">store_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="storeGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="storeGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">storeGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

I'm not 100% sure which files I need to include here. So if anyone need more information, please ask me :D

ResourceModel/Store.php

```
namespace Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel;


use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Store extends AbstractDb

{
    protected function _construct()

    {
        $this->_init('wavelabs_storelocator_store', 'store_id');

    }

}
```

ResourceModel/Store/Collection.php

```
namespace Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store;


use Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'store_id';

    /**
     * Load data for preview flag
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_previewFlag;

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\Store', 'Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\HelloWorld');
    }


    public function setFirstStoreFlag($flag = false)
    {
        $this->_previewFlag = $flag;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add filter by store
     *
     * @param int|array|\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store
     * @param bool $withAdmin
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
    {

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Perform operations after collection load
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {

        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Perform operations before rendering filters
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        return parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

Model/Store.php

```
namespace Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;


class Store extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you shared full code of that `Collection.php`?

Comment: Yes this is my full code of Grid/Collections.php

Comment: I think you forgot  to close `Collection` class `}`.

Comment: Please check there is no Typo in folder name
also check case sensitivity.

Comment: Try after `php bin/magento cache:flush`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` commands

Comment: The site is in developer mode. Do i still need to do setup:di:compile?

Comment: yes, some time we need to run that command or as Rutvee Sojitra told we can delete `generated` folder.

Comment: i did setup:di:compile and I got an error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection' not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Wavelabs/StoreLocator/Model/ResouceModel/Store/Grid/Collection.php on line 29

Comment: did you copy and paste those files?

Comment: I changed everything according to the answers given so far

Comment: You must check path of your grid collection, which should be app/code/Wavelabs/StoreLocator/Model/ResourceModel/Store/Grid/

Comment: O.M.G. i checked so many times that the obvious didnt work... indeed my path had Resouce instead of Resource...... ty ty ty

Comment: please share the screenshot of your module directory structure. @DavidKooijman

Comment: @KeyurShah ty for your answer, but the problem is already solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always good to check path letter by letter. What I had:

```
app/code/Wavelabs/StoreLocator/Model/ResouceModel/Store/Grid
```

What I need:

```
app/code/Wavelabs/StoreLocator/Model/ResourceModel/Store/Grid/
```

Feeling a bit like an idiot right now! But thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Please update your di.xml code with below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <virtualType name="Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
   <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">wavelabs_storelocator_stores</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">store_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">store_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="store_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
 <virtualType name="storeGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="storeGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">storeGirdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

after changing code fire two command:

> rm -rf generated/* and cache:clean
>   and check

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I now get Class Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store does not exist

Comment: @DavidKooijman, confirm that file and class exist

Comment: Can you please add your Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store code in question

Comment: I added the code. The class is there in my folder structure

Comment: @DavidKooijman
please edir one more line in di.xml
<argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>
to 

<argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>


here your Namespace is wrong and check after it

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: @DavidKooijman, Now again you need flush cache

Comment: I flushed the cache!

Comment: @DavidKooijman Can you please put your Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection code
Last try will help to reach you to solution. :)

Comment: I edited my question! Thank you for helping so far. I really appreciate it :D

Comment: protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\Store', 'Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\HelloWorld');
    }
please change this code with below
protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\Store', 'Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store');
    }
cache:clean and check

Comment: Totally missed that one :) still having the same error though

Comment: Not possible!!!!!!!! Have you clean your cache and load your admin grid after hard refresh?

Comment: Flushing and clearing as much as possible, but still having the same error -_- driving me crazy

Comment: @DavidKooijman
Please check in your Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\Store code
There is perfect resourceModel name?
or put that code in question

Comment: I think it is right. Added it to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82073/discussion-between-rutvee-sojitra-and-david-kooijman).

Answer (score 0):

In your di.xml, you have

```
<argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>
```

But based on the info you've provided, it should be

```
<argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Wavelabs\StoreLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this indeed helped solve the problem a little more. I answered my own question for what made it work fully again!